# CoreData "keypath not found " error does not state the missing key path

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a crash on production, and I see that the reason is this -

```
keypath not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Question id=25>
```

Now I know that usually, this error means that I am trying to set a key that does not exist n that entity, but this time I do not see the keypath itself in the error.

The other things that I know are that the crash occurs after a merge conflict and that is related to a constraint we set on the entity. And that the crash is on the saving block.

Any Ideas why the keypath is not stated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the code prior to the save doesn't appear to have changed in the merge, and you believe the conflict is in the Core Data model file itself, I'd recommend deleting and recreating the entity.

If my assumptions are incorrect, sharing more of the code that is causing the issue would be helpful.

The `keypath` not being stated is likely just an Xcode / merge conflict issue.